# Script to run against stdin if no arg; otherwise input file =ARGV[0]

Tags: ruby, file, stdin, idioms

This works quite nicely - just wondered if there are any improvements to shorten it ?

```
if (ARGV[0].nil?) then
    input=$<
else
    input=File.new(ARGV[0],"r");
end

...
# Do something with the input here, for example:
input.each_line do |line|
    puts line
end
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can eliminate the first five lines entirely.

From Pickaxe

> $<: An object that provides access to
>   the concatenation of the contents of
>   all the files given as command-line
>   arguments or $stdin (in the case where
>   there are no arguments).  $< supports
>   methods similar to a File object:
>   binmode, close, closed?, each,
>   each_byte, each_line, eof, eof?, file,
>   filename, fileno, getc, gets, lineno,
>   lineno=, path, pos, pos=, read,
>   readchar, readline, readlines, rewind,
>   seek, skip, tell, to_a, to_i, to_io,
>   to_s, along with the methods in
>   Enumerable. The method file returns a
>   File object for the file currently
>   being read. This may change as $<
>   reads through the files on the command
>   line. [r/o]

Therefore:

```
print $<.read
```

Kernel.gets is shorthand for $<.gets, so:

```
while s = gets
  puts s
end
```

Comment: Also, you can use `ARGF`, since it's an alias to `$<`.

Comment: yeah - that works great - it makes me wonder why I went round in circles the first time in order to catch this.

I think it's possibly because of the slightly odd (but good) behaviour that you if run 'ruby myscript.rb' without args, that the script simply just exits - most programs (certaintly on Unix for instance) will sit and wait for stdin : so I guess I assumed that I had to implement something there - but in fact (thanks for the description) the Ruby interpreter does something quite useful and quite clever (as usual) there !
Thanks.

Comment: I'm right there with you.  I'm still getting used to (and discovering) all of these little Ruby tricks.

Answer (score 3):

Only `ARGV ?` works for me, `"r"` normally default so can skip it, and `File.new()` may be same to `File()`, So

```
input = ARGV ? $< : File.new(ARGV[0])
```

Comment: File("foo") no longer seems to work (ruby 2.3.1): NoMethodError: undefined method `File' for main:Object.

Answer (score 2):

`then` and `;` are optional

also you can use the ternary operator:

```
input = ARGV[0].nil? ? $< : File.new(ARGV[0],"r")
```

Comment: Great - +1 - but I voted the other answer as it is even shorter !

Good old Ruby !