# Ruby Switch Between File and Standard Input

Tags: ruby, input, stdin, pipe

How would you create a variable that could be read. It would read from a certain file if it exists, otherwise it would read from standard input. Something like:

```
input = File.open("file.txt") || in
```

This doesn't work, but I think this should be done pretty often, but I can't find a nice way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See: [...run against stdin if no arg; otherwise input file =ARGV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2013428/ruby-nicer-way-of-doing-this-script-to-run-against-stdin-if-no-arg-otherwise/2013863#2013863)

Comment: As much as I hate cryptic naming schemes this is pretty useful.

Comment: Agree.  Well, there is ARGF.  Still cryptic, but not as bad as $<.

Answer (score 4):

This this works for you?

```
input = File.exist?("file.txt") ? File.open("file.txt") : STDIN
```

Comment: You can also use `$stdin` instead of `STDIN`.

Answer (score 1):

I think ruby has the ability to treat arguments that aren't used before STDIN is first used as if it were filenames for files piped into standard input.